# Does this NY Times article give a proper etymology of "procrastinate"?

Tags: etymology

A recent [*New York Times* article about procrastination](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/25/smarter-living/why-you-procrastinate-it-has-nothing-to-do-with-self-control.html) begins with an etymology lesson:

> Etymologically, “procrastination” is derived from the Latin verb *procrastinare* — to put off until tomorrow. But it’s more than just voluntarily delaying. Procrastination is also derived from the ancient Greek word *akrasia* — doing something against our better judgment.

The first part is obvious, but the second part struck me as odd, since I'm not aware of any etymological link between the Latin *cras* ("tomorrow") and Greek *κρατέω*, *krateō*, from which *akrasia* derives.

**Is this a valid etymology? If not, is it a common folk etymology, or just a one-off false claim by the article?**

Comment: I noticed too -- it looks like a bit of linguistic cluelessness on the part of the author and editor, who didn't stop to think about whether a word can be simultaneously derived from two separate words in different languages. It's just another example of how when it comes to claims about language in the popular press, anything goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It seems to be an invention of the author.

As you say, *procrastinate* comes from the Latin (from *cras* "tomorrow"). It's complete coincidence that it looks similar to *acrasia* "weakness of will"; the two have no etymological connection that I can find.

I can't find any other instances of this folk etymology on the web, so I would guess the author of this article just made it up.

Comment: While it's really not that important, a quick [Gooogle search for both terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=procrastination+akrasia) seems to show that this "relation" has been floating about for a while. It seems to me that the author merely made the conceptual leap from a vague claim of being "related" to a false claim of being "derived."